# Jquery Data Tables - How to do multicolumn sort and redraw table when click on header it can be asc or desc

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

[image: Requirement]

Hello All,
I am running into problem for Data table where I need to have Single column with One header "Number" which will have two sub header 1)Mobile 2) Cell.This column Header will Have same Data for Mobile / Cell. I have tried to explain the scenario with Screen shot.
Once I have that Column I need to click on Mobile which will sort same data with different sort sequence with [Orderdata](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderData) clause. c. if I click on Home it will have different multicolumn sort . I tried with Rowspan and colspan which is treating it as different column which will not work for me.
Please provide me suggestion. I have attached [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jordan_josh3184/pt9ovqku/5/) link and also pasted code for your reference.
Once I have these headers I will capture click event and get the name of the header and will redraw the table based on the header name.
First I would like to see even if its possible with Datatables. I am open for suggestions.
Js File:

```
  //Script
var data = [ {
    "FirstName" : "John",
    "LastName" : "Stroops",
    "City" : "Las Vegas",
    "Country" : "USA",
    "Office" : "Las Vegas",
    "Phone Number":"2045556789"
}, {
    "FirstName" : "Nick",
    "LastName" : "Jonas",
    "City" : "Los Angeles",
    "Country" : "USA",
    "Office" : "Los Angeles",
    "Phone Number":"2408564578"

}, {
    "FirstName" : "Priyanka",
    "LastName" : "Jonas",
    "City" : "New York",
    "Country" : "USA",
    "Office" : "New York",
    "Phone Number":"5612547845"
}
];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example thead').on('click', 'th', function () {
         var index = $('#example').DataTable().column(this).index();
          alert('index : '+index);
         
        });
    $('#example').DataTable( {
         data: data,
         "aaSorting": [],
         "columnDefs": [ 
             {"targets": [ 2 ],"visible": false,"searchable":true},
             {"targets": [ 3 ],"visible": true,"searchable":true},
             {"targets": [ 5 ],"visible": true,"searchable":false}
             ],
         columns: [
             { data: "FirstName","orderData": [0,1,2,3]}, 
             { data: "LastName","orderData": [0,2,3,4]},
             { data: "City","orderData": [0,2,3,4]},
             { data: "Country","orderData": [1,2] },
             { data: "Office","orderData": [4,0,1] },
             { data: "Phone Number","orderData": [5,1] }
         ]
    } );
} );
```

HTML:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
     .dataTable > thead > tr > th[class*="sort"]::after{display: none}
</style>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table id="example" class="display" style="width: 80%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>FirstName</th>
                    <th>LastName</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Phone number</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Thank you All

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reading my post. I have found the answer by using `initComplete:function()` and using the innerHTML. Now I am able to get the click event based on different columns.

```
  'initComplete: function() {
            const table = this.api();
            [1,2].forEach(column => table.column(column).header().innerHTML += '</br><span name="cell" class="cell">cell &nbsp;&nbsp;</span> </br> <span name="home" class="home">home</span>');
          }
$('span.home').on('click', function(event) {
        $('#example').DataTable().order( [[ 1, 'asc' ], [ 2, 'asc' ]] ).draw();
        //event.stopPropagation();
    });'
```

Can any one please Guide me How do multicolumn sort like I did with "orderData" and redraw the table. Click is coming from table header so it can be asc or desc. order has option asc or desc it cant be both.
Thank you

Comment: Glad you found a solution. You should post your question about multicolumn sorting as a new question, instead of asking it in an answer. People will be much more likely to see (and maybe answer) it, if it is its own question. (And assuming it's not a duplicate question).